Using sendGrid email Template, why is only some of my JsonObject data being displayed?
So I'm attempting to use dynamic data with handlebars in a sendgrid email template. In IntelliJ I printed the jsonObject so make sure it's formatted correctly. I then copy/pasted that output into sendgrid's test data. Everything appears as expected. However when I send the actually email, only some of the data is showing from the JsonObject.
Relevant code for iterating over the data(shows during test, but not during actual email)
<div style="font-family: inherit; text-align: center">
    {{#each topResults}}
    <p><a href="{{this.link}}">{{this.title}}</a></p>
    {{/each}}
</div>

This was my test data
{"size": "20.0x1x20","equipment": "Cabin","location": "Closet","topResults": [{"link": "https://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-20-in-x-20-in-x-1-in-Allergen-Plus-Pleated-Furnace-Air-Filter-FPR-7-MERV-11-HDX1P7-012020/314671519?g_store=6917&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&srsltid=AfmBOoqNOXu9An65sk3ZLOsq6L1_tgBsehEPmq2rXANL2IurKbeAgynxaHA","title": "20 in. x 20 in. x 1 in. Allergen Plus Pleated Air Filter FPR 7"},{"link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/125788359635?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28&var=426778963521&srsltid=AfmBOoq4JzECeCMPOSu82J40FpdFWjUFNpGCODeXz2IpSPZZSETo-TuNzRk&com_cvv=d30042528f072ba8a22b19c81250437cd47a2f30330f0ed03551c4efdaf3409e","title": "20 in. x 20 in. x 1 in. Standard Pleated Air Filter FPR 5 (3-pack)"},{"link": "https://www.homedepot.com/p/20-in-x-20-in-x-1-in-Fiberglass-Furnace-Air-Filter-MERV-1-11004-012020/315164974?g_store=6917&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&srsltid=AfmBOooUc58GVuvTZwwDnrm2qDhNppmevV1hZLxLmulIrvLl2jJ2oSjaIuo","title": "20 in. x 20 in. x 1 in. Fiberglass Air Filter FPR 1"}],"user": "Austin"}

In the actual email, the user, size, equipment, and location values are being displayed. However topResults only shows during sendGrid's email preview when I provide test data.
